# HTTPS access through Apache proxy: no valid certification path

Tags: java, apache, https, glassfish

I'm trying to configure SSL access using a frontend Apache (version 2.4.6) server as a ReverseProxy to serve multiple Java applications deployed on a backend server with glassfish (version 3.1.2.2).
Using virtualHost and ServerName, everything works fine with HTTP protocol:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName ppd-cas.capeb.fr
   # redirect "/" "https://ppd-cas.capeb.fr/cas"
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   RedirectMatch "/$" "/cas"
   ProxyPass "/cas" "http://10.1.93.10:34674/cas" retry=0 timeout=300 Keepalive=On
   ProxyPassReverse "/cas" "http://10.1.93.10:34674/cas"
</VirtualHost>
```

I configured the HTTPS (in ssl.conf) as follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName ppd-cas.capeb.fr

   SSLEngine on
   SSLProxyEngine on
   SSLProxyVerify none
   SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
   SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
   # SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/server.cert
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost on
   RedirectMatch "/$" "/cas"
   ProxyPass "/cas" "https://10.1.93.10:56912/cas" retry=0 timeout=300 Keepalive=On
   ProxyPassReverse "/cas" "https://10.1.93.10:56912/cas"
</VirtualHost>
```

The certificate is self-signed, generated and deployed on the frontend server. I thought I could go with HTTPS between browser and frontend then ignore certificate between frontend and backend thus the above options with "none" or "off" parameters.

The example provided (ppd-cas.capeb.fr) works fine using https, BUT, another application described below, with identical parameters, does not:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName ppd-isabat.capeb.fr

   SSLEngine on
   SSLProxyEngine on
   SSLProxyVerify none
   SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
   SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
   # SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/server.cert
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost on
   RedirectMatch "/$" "/CAPEBWeb"
   ProxyPass "/CAPEBWeb" "https://10.1.93.10:8181/CAPEBWeb" retry=0 timeout=300 Keepalive=On
   ProxyPassReverse "/CAPEBWeb" "https://10.1.93.10:8181/CAPEBWeb"
</VirtualHost>
```

The error I get in Glassfish logs is:

```
[#|2016-10-04T15:54:46.078+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=19;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[action]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The tricky part is that the application ppd-isabat.capeb.fr (the one that doesn't work) is deployed on the domain1 of Glassfish and uses CAS authentication, and CAS (the one that works) is deployed on domain2 of the same Glassfish. Trying to access ppd-isabat.capeb.fr (https://ppd-isabat.capeb.fr), I'm redirected correctly to the authentication pages of CAS, the error occurs after validating credentials. For me the different installation domain is part of the problem but it's just a hunch.

Does my approach (disabling SSL constraints between frontend and backend) is wrong ? am I missing something obvious ? Glassfish has embeded self-signed certificate so he should be able to identify himself ?

I search thoroughly StackOverflow, but none of the questions really matches this peculiar configuration.

Any help appreciated :)

PS: It's my 1st post, so please, don't be too harsh. I'm french, so please, don't be too harsh !

Answer (score 0):

You said in your post that you want to terminate `SSL` at Apache itself and the communication between Apache and `Glassfish` is meant to be HTTP(`non-ssl`) but yet you are passing requests to the backend with `https` URLs:

```
ProxyPass "/CAPEBWeb" "**https**://10.1.93.10:8181/CAPEBWeb" retry=0 timeout=300 Keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse "/CAPEBWeb" "**https**://10.1.93.10:8181/CAPEBWeb"
```

Shouldn't you be using http:// instead of https://?
You may also need to change the port from 8181 to something else depending on your glassfish's configuration.

Comment: I tried to set it as HTTP between Apache and Glassfish, but it didn't work. So I configured Apache to use HTTPS but ignore certificate using: SSLProxyVerify none, SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off and SSLProxyCheckPeerName off. 8181 is the port in Glassfish that listen for HTTPS traffic for domain1.

Comment: More precisely, ending https in Apache cause the following error: ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Seems like CAS is not happy with my current conf.